# Office 365 Powerpoint addon development how to add button controls (Ink and Draw) to task pane

Tags: office365, powerpoint, office-js, office-addins

I was trying to find API reference to add options for adding buttons in the task pane view which are there in the Draw toolbar ribbon.

Can anyone please suggest how to do this and can the task panes be shown during presentation or full screen view ?

Answer (score 0):

The scenario that you've described is not supported by Office JS. That is, it's not currently possible to create a task pane in PowerPoint which contains buttons that, by default, invoke the same functionality as native PowerPoint buttons in the ribbon.